# Hide the database schema and data in deployed Lightswitch / SQL Server 2012 LocalDb

Tags: sql-server-2012, visual-studio-lightswitch, localdb

I am creating a 2-tier Lightswitch application which will be deployed via ClickOnce for single-user scenarios. The database schema and the data need to be protected from access by the users.

I know that this might not be perfectly possible, but are there ANY solutions to this?

We looked at a 3rd-party tool called `DbDefence`, and it seemed like a perfect fit, but their redistribution licensing pricing is way over our budget right now.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way that I know of to prevent users from *viewing* or even *fiddling with* the database schema (if they're knowledgable enough). Unless you're creating the database for them, they have to have the permissions needed to be able to **create** the database. Plus updates (via Click-Once) would need **update** permissions on the tables.

The chances are, if you did find something, that it could prevent the application from working correctly anyway.